# Cassandra ring not showing all nodes

Tags: cassandra

I created three Cassandra nodes and generated 3 tokens (starting at 0) for them. I've also set the seeds in cassandra.yaml.

Here's my problem: If I set the "initial_token" field in cassandra.yaml, I can't see all nodes when I do a

```
 nodetool -h localhost ring
```

However, if I don't set it, I can see the entire ring working properly. Any idea what could cause this? What is the impact?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the tokens you are using? Sounds like your tokens are not configured correctly.

Comment: Did Cassandra start correctly on all nodes?  Check in cassandra.log and system.log (often in /var/log/cassandra)